Responsive navigation bar with dropdown buttons
The problem: in responsive view, dropdown button does not move to the visible navigation bar from the menu icon when any of its dropdown content is clicked.
In more detail: In responsive view (screen width under 730px), the navigation bar becomes a menu icon, and I want any <a> or dropdown <button> to move to the visible navigation bar when any dropdown item is clicked.

The code is at https://codepen.io/Balazs-Keisz/pen/KKOmgQX
Here's the JavaScript handling the navigation bar:
    // Function to toggle responsive class for topnav when icon is clicked
    function myFunctionIcon() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
    
    // Function to clear all highlights
    function clearAllHighlights() {
      // Remove highlight from all nav items and buttons
      document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item, .dropbtn').forEach(item => {
        item.classList.remove('highlight-menu');
      });
    }
    
    // Function to highlight the clicked button or link
    function highlightButton(clickedElement) {
      clearAllHighlights(); // Clear previous highlights
      clickedElement.classList.add('highlight-menu'); // Highlight the clicked element
      
      
    // If the clicked element is part of a dropdown, ensure only the dropdown button is highlighted
      const dropdownButton = clickedElement.closest('.dropdown')?.querySelector('.dropbtn');
      if (dropdownButton) {
        dropdownButton.classList.add('highlight-menu'); // Highlight only the dropdown button
      }
    }
    
    // Event listeners for nav items and dropbtns
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item, .dropbtn').forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        highlightButton(this); // Apply highlight
        // Prevent closing the menu when clicking the dropdown button
        if (this.classList.contains('dropbtn')) {
          event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event from bubbling up
        }
      });
    });
    
    // Event listener for each dropdown content link to close responsive menu
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content a').forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        const dropdownButton = this.closest('.dropdown').querySelector('.dropbtn');
        highlightButton(dropdownButton); // Highlight only the dropdown button
        if (window.innerWidth <= 729) {
          document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.remove("responsive"); // Close responsive menu
        }
      });
    });
    
    // Event listener for any other responsive <a> links to close the menu
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item').forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 729) {
          document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.remove("responsive"); // Close responsive menu
        }
      });
    });
    
    // Dropdown toggle function for multiple dropdowns
    function toggleDropdown1(dropdownId) {
      var dropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
      dropdown.classList.toggle("show1");
    }
    
    // Function to close all dropdowns
    function closeAllDropdowns() {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        dropdowns[i].classList.remove('show1');
      }
    }

    // Toggle dropdown for the clicked dropdown button
    function toggleDropdown1(dropdownContent) {
      // Check if the clicked dropdown is already open
      var isOpen = dropdownContent.classList.contains('show1');
      
      // Close all dropdowns
      closeAllDropdowns();

      // If the clicked dropdown was not open, open it
      if (!isOpen) {
        dropdownContent.classList.add('show1');
      }
    }

    // Add event listeners for each dropdown button
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn').forEach(button => {
      button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // Prevent closing on the same dropdown click
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Get the corresponding dropdown content
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;

        // Toggle the dropdown
        toggleDropdown1(dropdownContent);
      });
    });

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of any dropdown
    window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !event.target.matches('.dropbtn i')) {
        closeAllDropdowns();
      }
    });

    // Attach event listeners to all <a> and <button> elements for highlighting
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item, .dropbtn').forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        highlightButton(this); // Highlight the clicked element
      });
    });


The problem is with this part
// Event listener for each dropdown content link to close responsive menu
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content a').forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        const dropdownButton = this.closest('.dropdown').querySelector('.dropbtn');

You are selecting the wrong item
.querySelector('.dropbtn');
that is a child of the dropdown in question.
You can not show a child if it's parent is hidden!
So to fix this, remove last .querySelector('.dropbtn') and you are good to go.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto Serif' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        html {
            font-size: 17px;
            /* Base size */
        }

        body {
            font-family: 'Noto Serif';
            background-color: #eae6e0;
            padding: 0 0 50px 0;
        }

        /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
        .topnav {
            background-color: #404857;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            /* Use flexbox for alignment */
            justify-content: center;
            /* Distribute buttons evenly */
        }

        /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .topnav .search-container {
            float: right;
            display: none;
        }

        .topnav .search-container input[type=text] {
            padding: 6px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            border: none;
        }

        .topnav .search-container button {
            float: right;
            padding: 6px 10px;
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-right: 16px;
            background: #ddd;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        /* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        /* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
        .dropbtn {
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: #404857;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: 1rem;
            margin: 0;
        }

        /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        /* Style the links inside the dropdown */
        .dropdown-content a {
            float: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        /* Highlight topnav links, dropdown button and search-container on hover */
        .topnav a:hover,
        .dropbtn:hover {
            color: #ffa668;
        }

        /* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: #0036cf;
        }

        /* Highlight the current page */
        .highlight-menu {
            background-color: #0036cf;
            color: white;
        }

        .dropdown-content.show1 {
            display: block;
        }

        /* When the screen is less than 730 pixels wide, hide all links. Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
        @media screen and (max-width: 729px) {
            .topnav {
                display: block;
                /* Remove flexbox layout */
                justify-content: initial;
                /* Reset justify content */
            }

            .topnav a,
            .dropdown,
            .dropbtn,
            .dropdown-content {
                display: none;
                /* Hide by default */
            }

            .highlight-menu {
                display: block !important;
                /* Ensure highlighted elements are displayed */
            }

            .topnav .dropbtn.highlight-menu {
                display: block;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                /* Show icon to toggle menu */
            }

            .show1 {
                display: block;
                /* Ensure dropdown contents are visible */
            }

            /* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
            @media screen and (max-width: 729px) {
                .topnav.responsive {
                    position: relative;
                }

                .topnav.responsive a {
                    float: none;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown,
                .dropbtn {
                    float: none;
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: left;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
                    position: relative;
                }
            }
        }
    </style>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

        <!-- NOTE: ADDDED THIS CODE -->
        <div id="tab1"></div>
        <div id="tab2"></div>
        <div id="tab3"></div>
        <div id="tab4"></div>
        <div id="tab5"></div>
        <!-- NOTE: ADDDED THIS CODE -->

        <!-- The menu icon (mobile view) -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunctionIcon()">&#9776;</a>

        <!-- Navigation items (links and buttons) -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <!-- NOTE: REMOVE CALL IN onclick ', toggleDropdown1('myDropdown2')' -->
            <button onclick="highlightButton(this)" class="dropbtn">Intro
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('tab1').click();">Creator's Note</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('tab2').click();">Fan Note</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#cards" id='cards' class="nav-item">Cards</a>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <!-- NOTE: REMOVE CALL IN onclick ', toggleDropdown1('myDropdown2')' -->
            <button onclick="highlightButton(this)" class="dropbtn">Rules
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('tab3').click();">Table of Contents</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('tab4').click();">Diagrams</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('tab5').click();">Rule Book Viewer</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#strategies" id='strategies' class="nav-item">Strategies</a>
        <a href="#resources" id='resources' class="nav-item">Resources</a>
        <a href="#about" id='about' class="nav-item">About</a>
        <a href="#contact" id='contact' class="nav-item">Contact</a>
    </div>
</head>
<script>
    // Function to toggle responsive class for topnav when icon is clicked
    function myFunctionIcon() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }

    // Function to clear all highlights
    function clearAllHighlights() {
        // Remove highlight from all nav items and buttons
        document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item, .dropbtn').forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('highlight-menu');
        });
    }

    // Function to highlight the clicked button or link
    function highlightButton(clickedElement) {
        clearAllHighlights(); // Clear previous highlights
        clickedElement.classList.add('highlight-menu'); // Highlight the clicked element


        // If the clicked element is part of a dropdown, ensure only the dropdown button is highlighted
        const dropdownButton = clickedElement.closest('.dropdown')?.querySelector('.dropbtn');
        if (dropdownButton) {
            dropdownButton.classList.add('highlight-menu'); // Highlight only the dropdown button
        }
    }

    // Event listeners for nav items and dropbtns
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item, .dropbtn').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            highlightButton(this); // Apply highlight
            // Prevent closing the menu when clicking the dropdown button
            if (this.classList.contains('dropbtn')) {
                event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event from bubbling up
            }
        });
    });

    // Event listener for each dropdown content link to close responsive menu
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content a').forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // NOTE: SELKECSELECT THE .dropdown item, not it's child
            const dropdownButton = this.closest('.dropdown');//.querySelector('.dropbtn');
            highlightButton(dropdownButton); // Highlight only the dropdown button
            if (window.innerWidth <= 729) {
                document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.remove("responsive"); // Close responsive menu
            }
        });
    });

    // Event listener for any other responsive <a> links to close the menu
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item').forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (window.innerWidth <= 729) {
                document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.remove("responsive"); // Close responsive menu
            }
        });
    });

    // Dropdown toggle function for multiple dropdowns
    function toggleDropdown1(dropdownId) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
        dropdown.classList.toggle("show1");
    }

    // Function to close all dropdowns
    function closeAllDropdowns() {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            dropdowns[i].classList.remove('show1');
        }
    }

    // Toggle dropdown for the clicked dropdown button
    function toggleDropdown2(dropdownContent) {
        // Check if the clicked dropdown is already open
        var isOpen = dropdownContent.classList.contains('show1');

        // Close all dropdowns
        closeAllDropdowns();

        // If the clicked dropdown was not open, open it
        if (!isOpen) {
            dropdownContent.classList.add('show1');
        }
    }

    // Add event listeners for each dropdown button
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // Prevent closing on the same dropdown click
            event.stopPropagation();

            // Get the corresponding dropdown content
            var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;

            // Toggle the dropdown
            toggleDropdown2(dropdownContent);
        });
    });

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of any dropdown
    window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !event.target.matches('.dropbtn i')) {
            closeAllDropdowns();
        }
    });

    // Attach event listeners to all <a> and <button> elements for highlighting
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item, .dropbtn').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function () {
            highlightButton(this); // Highlight the clicked element
        });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>




Thank you, though I still have an issue. With your tip, dropdown buttons move from the menu icon, but now all clicked dropdown buttons move. I only want one clicked element to move at a time, either it is a "simple"  or a dropdown.

As I've pointed out - you can not display a child component (that is a  element) of your dropdown, while the dropdown itself is hidden. To do what you want, there are two options:


reconsider your structure so that you have two menus - one for desktop and one for responsive modes, then display 'desktop' items when they are selected on responsive layout


programmatically pick clicked element (the ) and put it into the root of your toolbar when clicked in responsive mode


